# Showing beta versions of an app to a customer

Tags: ios, xcode

1. Can I send to my customer a beta version of my iOS app that he can run in the Simulator ?
2. Can I install Simulator only (without Xcode) on a Mac ?

I actually need an efficient methodology to send him the beta versions of the app, without having to meet him at each update.

Also, (3.) is there a way to install a beta version of the app, I developed in my xCode on its iOS device without app store ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, I do not believe you can.
2. No, I don't think so. If you could, however, you'd also have to put all your source code on that machine and build your app there, just to run it in the simulator.
3. Yes, it's called an Ad Hoc build. You create a special provisioning profile through the provisioning portal on Apple's Developer portal. You then sign the build with that provisioning profile (actually, "Build and Archive"). Then you can, through the Xcode Organizer, share that build via e-mail with your customer. The Organizer creates an .ipa file and includes it along with the provisioning profile into an e-mail message which you can then compose and send.

Edit: The Ad Hoc provisioning profile will, of course, need to include the UDID's of your customer's device(s) on which they would like to test. That is the missing piece here that ties it all together: UDIDs, Ad Hoc profile, signed app with that profile, e-mail it to the customer and they can install both files (ipa and profile) via iTunes.

Lots of documentation on this, right in the Developer portal.

Answer (score 3):

[TestFlightApp.com](http://TestFlightApp.com) is a great way to easily manage and distribute beta tests and ad-hoc builds.  It's nothing you couldn't do yourself, manually, but it really helps make it easy, and is free.