# Load custom app into an iOS device without jailbreaking it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, testing, ad-hoc-distribution

If I sign an application with a legit developer license, is it possible to install some developer preview of it into an iOS device without jailbreaking it?

Saw some similar questions, but they didn't clearly answer this question for me.

Comment: See questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083959/showing-beta-versions-of-an-app-to-a-customer. The keyword you want to look out for is AdHoc Distribution.

Comment: look into adhoc distributions.  essentially, it's how folks distribute to testers before publishing

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the wrong words. If some of you can reply so I can mark the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get this question solved, I am adding my comment as an answer.

See questions like [Showing beta versions of an app to a customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083959/showing-beta-versions-of-an-app-to-a-customer).

The keyword you want to look out for is

> AdHoc Distribution

The basic procedure involves adding the UDID's of your test-devices to your developer account and enable them for your test-app's.

For details on this procedure you may also check Apple's documentation on the subject [Distributing Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html)

Comment: As the linked answer says, I highly recommend using TestFlight for this.